# VLC silent install over Powershell

Tags: powershell, vlc

I'm trying to install the VLC media player using a PowerShell script.

I opened the VLC wiki and found this (that's the only help I found online):

`Start process -FilePath "C: \ Temp \ VLC.exe" -ArgumentList "/ L = 1033 / S"`

When I run this command I don't get an error, but I have to accept the Windows admin thing and that's it. VLC cannot be installed.

Comment: I'd remove all the unnecessary spaces in your path and arguments. And of course you have to run this elevated to able to install a software.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your fast solution. I got it to work with your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without powershell.  I'm not sure why people jump so often to start-process.  I guess it won't work if you quote the command.  It can be run directly:

```
.\vlc-3.0.11-win32.exe /L=1033 /S
```

Msi version:

```
install-package vlc-3.0.16-win64.msi
```

Default preferences file for ignoring update prompts, etc.  copy-item overwrites without a confirmation.

```
copy-item vlcrc C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install software using Chocolatey. This is very simple, it's PowerShell based and consists in only 1 command line (but first you need to install Chocolatey):

```
choco install vlc
```

And it's very easy to update installed software as well.